# Comparing different columns of 2 csv files

Tags: csv, powershell

I am trying to compare 2 colums in 2 csv files with eachother so that i can check if there are differences in the 2 files. 
Because 1 of the files is a export from a incident management system, the headers that are being used are different. This means that i have to compare the items under the first header of the first file(Meldings-nummer) to the ones under the second header of the second file, which is Incidentnummer.

I got it to work if the headers are the same, using following code. 
However, this doesnt work using different headernames and it also doesn´t show the results.

```
$firstFile = read-host - prompt "Please input exact file location of first .csv file"
$secFile = read-host - prompt "Please input exact file location of second .csv file"
$ff = Import-Csv $firstFile
$sf = Import-Csv $secFile
Compare-Object -referenceobject $ff -differenceobject $sf -includeequal |Where-Object {$_.SideIndicator -ne "=="} |Select -ExpandProperty InputObject
```

Or, using the easier version that shows only meldings-nummer:

```
$file1 = import-csv -Path "C:\Users\Documents\scripts\Powershell\Overzicht_Meldingen_2015-10-21.csv" 
$file2 = import-csv -Path "C:\Users\Documents\scripts\Powershell\Overzicht_Meldingen_2015-10-21aangepast.csv" 
Compare-Object $file1 $file2 -property Meldings-nummer
```

This is the one that´s preferred, but then with the flexibility of the first one(having to manually enter the file location)

Does anyone know how to, or have any tips so i can archieve the comparing of different columns and showing them?

**UPDATE**
I just found some code that i adjusted. I think this should compare the 2 files and give a new file that shows the differences. 
Even though it executes fine and gives me the file, there is nothing in the file except for the text 'Wijziging'.

```
 $OldCSV = import-csv -Path "C:\Users\Documents\scripts\Powershell\Overzicht_Meldingen_2015-10-21.csv" 
 $NewCSV = import-csv -Path "C:\Users\Documents\scripts\Powershell\Overzicht_Meldingen_2015-10-21aangepast.csv" 

 $output = @()  
     forEach ($Column in $OldCsv) {      
        $result = $NewCSV | Where-Object {$Column."Meldings-nummer" -eq          $_.Incidentnummer}  
        $Melding = if ($Column.Powerstate -ne $result.PowerState)    {"Previous: " + $Column."Meldings-nummer" + " | Now:" + $result.Incidentnummer}  
         $output += New-object PSObject -property @{  
         #VMname = $Column.Name  
         Wijziging = $Melding  

       }  
     }  
   $output | select-object Wijziging | Export-Csv -Path    C:\Users\Documents\scripts\Powershell\Changes.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve here. Do you want to match different lines also or do you want to compare line 1 with line 1, line 2 with line 2 etc. from the two files?

Comment: What i want to do is compare the 2 files and see if there are codes in file 2 that are not in file 1 and vice versa (Codes being incident- and changenumbers) So it has to check if for example incident I1509-2954 from file 1 also exists in file 2. It is possible that it is placed on a other row. In file 1 i use the column Meldings-nummer to store the codes, file2 uses Incidentnummer to store the codes.

Comment: And are these numbers in sequential order in both files? 

What puzzles me is that you have a Previous: and a Now: in your message. How do you determine which number is Previous and which number is Now?

Comment: Hey, No, the previous and now can be removed, they are from the example i found. I also already tried without the if but with just  `$Melding = $NewCSV | Where-Object {$Column.Meldingsnummer -ne $result.Incidentnummer} `  but without succes. What i do get is the following: ,"                                                                                                                   "  as result per row

Comment: And what about the sort order in the files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the first file has the Meldings-nummer in ascending sequence and the second file has the Incidentnummer in ascending sequence, you could do it like this:

```
[int] $i = 0
[int] $j = 0
while ($i -le $ff.Count)
{
    if ($ff[$i].'Meldings-nummer' -lt $sf[$j].IncidentNummer -or $j -gt $sf.Count)
    { 
        Write-Host ("Meldings-nummer {0} not in second file." -f $ff[$i].'Meldings-nummer')
        $i++
    }
    while ($ff[$i].'Meldings-nummer' -gt $sf[$j].IncidentNummer -or $i -gt $ff.Count)
    {
        if ($j -ge $sf.Count)
            { break }
        Write-Host ("IncidentNummer {0} not in first file." -f $sf[$j].IncidentNummer)
        $j++
    }
    if ($ff[$i].'Meldings-nummer' -eq $sf[$j].IncidentNummer)
    { 
        $j++ 
        $i++
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks for al the help but i think i solved it myself using the following code.

```
$file1 = import-csv -Path "C:\Users\Documents\scripts\Powershell\Overzicht_Meldingen_2015-10-21.csv" -header Meldings-nummer
$file2 = import-csv -Path "C:\Users\Documents\scripts\Powershell\Tweedelijns_incidenten14.csv" -header Incidentnummer 
Where-Object {$File1."Meldings-nummer" -ne $file2.Incidentnummer}
Compare-Object $file1 $file2
```

Now i can put the finishing touch in it so it ask for the csv files like in the first code